# Having trouble with mysql count

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error after execute my query

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '*) as totalcontents from contents as c inner join categories as
>   cat ON cat.id = ' at line 1

My sql like this

```
select z.name as zone_name, COUNT(c.*) as totalcontents 
from contents as c 
inner join categories as cat 
ON cat.id = c.category_id 
inner join zones as z 
ON z.id = cat.zone_id where c.created_by = 14 group by z.id
```

Comment: try `COUNT(c.id) as totalcontents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `INNER JOIN` then `COUNT(*)` is ok to use.

```
select z.name as zone_name, COUNT(*) as totalcontents  ....
```

OR

```
select z.name as zone_name, COUNT(z.name) as totalcontents  ....
```

[Go through this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58802)

Comment: you are specify group by z.id and select with z.name, it is not given error

Comment: Column 'z.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: My answer only solves the error it was getting. `COUNT(*)` also solves the problem. And in my example i am not using any `GROUP BY` I think.

Answer (score 0):

When you use group by function to specify column to display column other column to display given error. I think you try this

```
select z.name as zone_name, COUNT(z.name) as totalcontents 
from contents as c 
inner join categories as cat 
ON cat.id = c.category_id 
inner join zones as z 
ON z.id = cat.zone_id where c.created_by = 14 group by z.name
```

or

```
select z.name as zone_name,totalcontents 
from zones as z
join (select z.id as id, COUNT(z.id) as totalcontents 
    from contents as c 
    inner join categories as cat 
    ON cat.id = c.category_id 
    inner join zones as z 
    ON z.id = cat.zone_id where c.created_by = 14 group by z.id) a
ON z.id = a.id
```